# cisco hub-spoke ipsec vpn, ping between spokes

Tags: vpn, cisco, ipsec

I have a hub-spoke vpn setup between different locations,

```
Hub: 10.10.10.0/24 
A: 192.168.2.0/24
B: 192.168.41.0/24
```

There is ipsec vpn tunnel between Hub-A, and Hub-B, and the connection is fine. However, I can't ping B from A. The connection needs to go through Hub. I'm wondering what settings need to be made for the connection to work?

I tried to use NAT to translate A's address into Hub's but doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using IOS router or ASA?

Comment: i'm using IOS. basically I can see A&B from Hub, can see Hub from A, but not B from A.

Comment: it's solved, turns out to be nat rules issue.

Comment: @Daniel you should post what you did to fix it.